# Wrong mime type in windows browser for text/csv files

Tags: javascript, html, file, mime-types

I am validating file by checking mime type of file after upload complete.

I am using file object to determine the mime type of file.

This process works very well on Linux and Mac but in windows it shows empty string for text/csv files.

code for reference -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

    <input type="file" accept=".csv" onChange="myFunction(event)">

    <script>
       function myFunction(event) {
         console.log(event.target.files[0].type);
         document.write(event.target.files[0].type);
     }
    </script>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The `type` property is only set by looking at the extension anyway, you should not rely on this.

Comment: @Kaiido any better suggestions please

Comment: Depends on what you want to do... A csv file is just a plain/text file which occurs to have at least one `,` but usually several ones. If you want to check that it is a valid CSV file, then you'd have to parse it completely. But if you were ok with just `text/comma-separeted-value`, then just check for `file.name.split('.').pop() === 'csv'`

Comment: @Kaiido The solution you suggested will work but what if attacker used tricky name to upload wrong file?

Comment: Then even checking for `file.type` would not protect you. This kind of test should be done server-side anyway, but if you want to ensure that a file is really a csv file, the only way is to try to parse it.

Comment: Same issue - https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/391